# Java nio: Multithreading with DirectoryStream

Tags: java, multithreading, nio

I have an occasional hard to replicate bug where one of my threads hangs.

- A web spider thread dumps html files into a directory.
- A file processing thread reads the files in the directory, process
  them one by one and moves them.

Since the file processor move file (by logical necessity) can only occur when a file is already in the directory, the file processor file read process is asynchronous and unlikely to lead to a hang.

HOWEVER, the fileprocessor thread also scans the directory and this can happen as the web spider thread saves a file into the directory.

**QUESTION:**
If a file is saved into this directory while the following read directory method is called, will it cause a hang? (Frankly, I don't see how it could, but maybe that is why I have tthe bug).

If yes, then how do I resolve the issue?

```
 private void listFiles(Path path)
{
    Log.getLogger().debug("started ......");
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path))
    {
        for (Path entry : stream)
        {
            if (Files.isDirectory(entry))
            {
                listFiles(entry);
            }
            else
            {
                files.add(entry);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.getLogger().error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    Log.getLogger().debug("done");
}
```

Comment: Use *one* `ReentrantLock`. Call `lock()` when writing your files, `unlock()` when you're done. Then on the other Thread call `lock()` before doing scanning / copying and `unlock()` when done. This should give you an idea whether it is related to the threads interfering in each others work or not. It will prevent the threads from doing work when another thread has acquired the lock at that time.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Do you want to post this as an answer? Even if it doesn't solve my problem, it is sound advice and a necessary diagnostic step

Answer (score 0):

To avoid threads from interfering in each others work a semaphore (or mutex in it's simplest form) should be used. Sempaphores can be acquired by a thread in order to run code in the so called *critical section*. Code in this section could for example access an `ArrayList`. If multiple threads access that list and add and remove elements to and from it, you will eventually get a `ConcurrentModificationException`. In other cases you will not get an exception at all but your program might do unexpected things (see [the lost-update problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write%E2%80%93write_conflict) for example).

If you however acquire a lock each time you access the critical section, other threads won't be able to access the shared resource (the list in this case or the directory in your case).

In order to achieve this behaviour you can either use classes that implement the [lock interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html), create an object and use that as a lock like so:

```
Object lock = new Object();

synchronized(lock) {
  // do critical work here
}
```

A third and probably the most uneffective (but simplest) way is to use the `synchronized` keyword for your methods. Only one method that is declared as synchronized inside a class can be called at a time.

Comment: There is no concurrent modification issue here, is there? One thread is reading from a directory. Another may be adding files synchronously.

Comment: As stated in my answer, it doesn't have to be a `ConcurrentModificationException` it might even be **no exception at all** but some weird and unexpected behaviour instead.